# Creating a new service layer for controller gives an error called "ReflectionException" in Laravel 5

Tags: php, service, architecture, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I have created one service folder inside app. I am trying to access the class of service folder from a controller method. I have tried

> method injection

as well as

> contructor injection

. Both way I am getting the error :

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 833:
Class app\Services\NameOTheClass does not exist
```

Comment: did you import the class name on top of controller file, & check the namespace of your service file